# Using Erlang to read a whole text file into a variable, do text replacement and write modified file to new directory

Tags: file, erlang, full-text-search, variable-assignment

Problem: want to read content of a file (size less than 1MB) into a Erlang variable,
do some text replacement and write modified contents to a new file. I am new to Erlang and
want to use simple code with no error handling (use it from Erlang shell).

I have tried:

```
File = file:read_file("pbd4e53e0.html").
```

But when using

```
string:len(File).
```

I get

> exception error: bad argument in function  length/1
>   called as length({ok,<<">}) in call from string:len/1 (string.erl, line 66).

Next step is to do replacement:

```
re:replace(File, "<a href=\'pa", "<a href=\'../pa/pa", [{return, list}]).
```

Question 1: How should I read the file into an Erlang variable?

Question 2: Is the replacement ok?

Answer (score 9):

For the first question, [`file:read_file/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_file-1) returns a tuple of `{Status, Result}`, so the assignment should rather be like:

```
{ok, File} = file:read_file("pbd4e53e0.html").
```

Second, `File` will be a binary, not a string, so you need to convert it to a string first:

```
Content = unicode:characters_to_list(File).
```

(You can provide the [encoding argument](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_list-2) as well)

Then `string:len(Content)` will work as expected.

As for the replacements part, it's generally a [very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/770830) to use regex with HTML, but from the API point of view looks ok.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.

I have replaced:
 Content = unicode:characters_to_list(File).
with:
 Content = binary_to_list(File).
/Paul